# Acceder a valores enviados por formulario HTML en PHP

Tags: php, html, formularios

Perdon si cometo algún error, pero soy nuevo en este foro.

Quiero hacer una decisión en un bloque de php usando un valor de un select.

```
<?php
        $act = $_GET["act"];
        $save = $_GET["save"];
        if($act == 'agregar'){
            if($save == 'true'){


                //IF con las acciones del SELECT
                if("Variable"=='Centro de Cómputo'){
                    //Accion a realizar
                    $agregar=$s->agregar_solicitud();
                }
                if ("Varialble"=='Mantenimiento de Equipo') {
                    //Accion a realizar
                     $agregar=$s->agregar_solicitud_mantto();
                }
                echo "<script>window.location='/solicitud'; </script>";         
            }
    ?>
```

Y tengo el SELECT HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label letras-login bajar-letra" style="text-align: left;">Solicitar a:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <select name="bitacora" id="bitacora" onchange="habilitarCombo(this.value);" class="form-control" required>
                                                <option value="" style="display:none;">Elija una opcion</option>
                                                <option value="Centro de Cómputo">Centro de Cómputo</option>
                                                <option value="Mantenimiento de Equipo">Mantenimiento de Equipo</option>
                                            </select>   
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Una recomendación: si estás en PHP, usa `header` para redireccionar en lugar de mandar la redirección a JavaScript. Tal y como está ahora, se está creando tráfico innecesario que puede afectar negativamente tanto al cliente como al servidor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para empezar hay que saber mediante qué método vas a enviar el valor de este select al script PHP para que lo procese. Yo voy a ir a lo sencillo, un formulario mediante POST que se encargue de ello.

```html
<form action="procesar.php?act=XXX&save=XXX" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label letras-login bajar-letra" style="text-align: left;">Solicitar a:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select name="bitacora" id="bitacora" onchange="habilitarCombo(this.value);" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="" style="display:none;">Elija una opcion</option>
        <option value="Centro de Cómputo">Centro de Cómputo</option>
        <option value="Mantenimiento de Equipo">Mantenimiento de Equipo</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Esto enviará por POST el valor de todos los elementos contenidos en el formulario, lo que hará que en el lado servidor se cree una variable especial llamada `$_POST` que es un array cuyos índices corresponden a cada uno de estos elementos. Para acceder a estos valores solo tienes que acceder al índice de este array correspondiente al elemento:

```
echo $_POST['bitacora'];
```

El valor de este índice lo establecerá el valor que hayas dado al elemento en su atributo `name`. De esta manera, en tu código tendrás:

```
<?php
    $act = $_GET["act"];
    $save = $_GET["save"];
    if($act == 'agregar'){
        if($save == 'true'){


            //IF con las acciones del SELECT
            if($_POST['bitacora'] == 'Centro de Cómputo'){
                //Accion a realizar
                $agregar=$s->agregar_solicitud();
            }
            if ($_POST['bitacora'] == 'Mantenimiento de Equipo') {
                //Accion a realizar
                 $agregar=$s->agregar_solicitud_mantto();
            }
            echo "<script>window.location='/solicitud'; </script>";         
        }
?>
```

Esta es la manera más sencilla de acceder a valores enviados desde un formulario, aunque no es la más segura ni la más recomendable. Existen riesgos de inyección de código, entre otros. Puedes echar un vistazo an SO en español para solventar este tipo de problemas o realizar una búsqueda en google, hay mucha información sobre ello.

Comment: ¿Por qué no `header('Location: '/solicitud'); die();` en lugar de hacerlo mediante JavaScript?

Comment: @guzgarcia, porque la publicación original lo hace así, y no he querido confundirlo. La respuesta resuelve estrictamente la pregunta .